# extracting every html tag in body using PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I would like to count the number of characters and tags for each node in body tag. Later, this number of characters and tags will be used to get the density for each tag. To get the body, I use the function find() from [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

```
function FindBody($str) {
// String --> DOM Elements
$string = str_get_html($str);
// Find body
$e = $string->find('body');
file_put_contents('text_1.txt', $e);  }
```

The above snippet will get the following output:

`<body class="html not-front not-logged-in one-sidebar sidebar-first page-node page-node- page-node-163472 node-type-article page- page- ltr"><div id="skip-link"> <a href="#main-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable">Skip to main content</a>..... </body>`

The body will differ everytime I get the HTML from a link. Now, I'm stuck. I dont know how to iterate/recursively to get each tag. I have read somewhere, it can be done recursively, but it will take a lot of time.

I need to use the DOM as I'm following this an algorithm.

Comment: One practical technique is to use **XSLT.** This is a declarative language that in effect allows you to "query" an XML-like structure. I'll leave you to "Google it" to understand more of what I mean. But it basically means that you don't have to "write a complicated *program"* in order to get information from a complicated XML/XHTML source.

Comment: What do you mean by number of characters of each node exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want only texts to count then why not use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)